# What iOS / iPhone system keyboard has search functionality like the emoji keyboard?

Tags: ios, keyboard, ipad

Is there a system keyboard for iPhone (iOS) or iPad (iPad OS) that has search functionality, just like the system emoji keyboard has?

(Search functionality in the actual system keyboard, not in some app.)

### iOS System keyboard: Emoji (with search functionality):

[image: iOS Emoji System Keyboard with search functionality]

### System keyboards *without* search functionality

#### [Unichar](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/unichar-unicode-keyboard/id880811847)

[image: iOS System Keyboard: Unichar (without search functionality)]

Comment: Why do you call Unichar a "system keyboard"?  It's an app you have to download from the app store.  The people who make it would need to add search functionality.

Comment: Unichar is both an app and a system keyboard. Once you install the app, you can install the system keyboard (that does _not_ have a search feature).

Comment: I think all the 3rd party keyboard apps with character search rely on copy/paste for input into other apps.